# MySQL Many Rows Examined by Simple Query

Tags: mysql, rows, examine

There is a table tb_tag_article like

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_tag_article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `key_tag_id_article_id` (`tag_id`,`article_id`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=365944 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

When I query like this, the result is **5120**.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tb_tag WHERE tag_id = 43
```

But when I explain the query like this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM tb_tag WHERE tag_id = 43
```

examined rows is **13634**.

```
+------+-------------+----------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys         | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tb_tag_article | ref  | key_tag_id_article_id | key_tag_id_article_id | 4       | const | 13634 | Using index |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

The query use Index but the numbers of examined rows greater than count of real data.
What's the problem?

Comment: Let me guess: Your table contains 13k rows and 5k of them have the tag_id 43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q: What's the problem?**

**A:** It doesn't look like there's any problem.

The value for the "`rows`" column in the EXPLAIN output is an estimate, not an exact number.

Ref: [**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html)

---

For evaluating the "cost" of each possible access path, the optimizer only needs estimates in order to compare the efficiency of using a range scan operation on index vs. a full scan of all rows in the table. The optimizer doesn't need "exact" counts of the total number rows in the table, or the number of rows that will satisfy a predicate.

For this simple query, there are only a couple of possible plans that MySQL will consider.

And that estimate of 13684 isn't that far off from the exact count of rows. It's off by a factor of 2.5, but MySQL is coming up with the right execution plan: using the index, rather than checking every row in the table.

There is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL reference (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows):

> The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must
>   examine to execute the query.
>
> For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be
>   exact.

It might also be that because it has to analyze the index it takes into account the number of records in the index plus the number of records in the table. But that's just a hypothesis.

Also, it looks like there was a bug in MySQL 5.1 with Explain Row estimation causing the number to be wildly off: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53761 Depending on your version, this might explain some of the oddities.

The main take-away from the documentation seems to be to tree the EXPLAIN rows column with a grain of salt.